# Will the Dawnguard attempt to kill me if I become a Vampire?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

I have just completed the main Dawnguard Questline and have killed Harkon. I was considering turning into a vampire lord because Serana gives me the opportunity to become a vampire.

Will the Dawnguard attack and kill me if I turn into a vampire via Serana? Or will they kill Serana for turning me into a vampire?

Answer (score 8):

They won't attack you more than the guards would. So, unless you feed on somebody right in front of them, or become aggressive, you will be safe.

However, [they won't be your allies anymore](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Dawnguard_(Faction)#Guild_perks), refusing to talk to you and to give you access to their Fort.

Comment: Will they attack if I go into their fort

Comment: Not sure. Maybe, or maybe only if you try to steal something. That I don't know for sure.

Comment: What was your source?

Comment: Can you send link

Answer (score 0):

No, they will no not attack you.

I sided with the Dawnguard and became a vampire lord after finishing their main quest.

Every NPC at the fort tells me to get cured, but none attacks me.

Get cured if you need to buy crossbow bolts, get more radiant quests or use other services that the npc's provide.

Serana can reinfect you unlimited times if you have not persuaded her to get cured herself.

Comment: how do they know you're a vampire if  you're not in vampire lord form

Comment: @user4951 its just how its scripted. And in terms of story, they can probably tell visually. It is quite obvious.

Answer (score -1):

I had harkon or whatever his name is turn me and little groups of dawnguard like the bandit thugs show up randomly and attack me.